# Formula field to include the check for additional status values

Tags: formula

Is it possible to make changes to the conditions of any existing formula  so that it includes prior status as 'Pending', 'InProgress', 'OnHold'.

Current formula is below

```
AND(Account.Fragment__c = 'Solutions', ISPICKVAL(Status,"Rejected"), Original_Case_Requestor__r.On_Leave__c,Prior_Status__c = 'New')
```

Please let me know if it is possible.

Comment: Did you face any issue adding these conditions?

Comment: Yes, it is possible make changes to the conditions of any existing formula. Vishal, have you tried adding the stated conditions? If yes, what was the formula you opted for and what is the exact issue that you are facing. Please note that this forum helps individuals get answers to specific problems which they counter during development and not a free coding service!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following formula field to include the check for additional status values.

```
AND(
    Account.Fragment__c = 'Solutions', 
    ISPICKVAL(Status,"Rejected"), 
    Original_Case_Requestor__r.On_Leave__c,
    OR(
        Prior_Status__c = 'New',
        Prior_Status__c = 'Pending',
        Prior_Status__c = 'InProgress',
        Prior_Status__c = 'OnHold'
    )
)
```

Comment: @VishalNayak your welcome. Glad I could help!